# SOAPUI Load Custom Properties from file using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to write a groovy script which loads the custom properties for a test suite using information from a properties file.
The properties file has around 6 different attributes
I have had a look at quite a few different methods i.e Loading from Properties test step and trying to expand the properties with groovy, but have not been successful.

If anyone could advise on how to achieve this, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a *.properties file? if not can you give an example for the file content?

Comment: its a .txt file and the file content is something like username=XXX password=YYY, it just has configuration information in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the groovy script which reads a property file and set them at `test suite level`:

```groovy
def props = new Properties()
//replace the path with your file name below. use / instead of \ as path separator even on windows platform.
new File("/absolute/path/of/test.properties").withInputStream { s ->
  props.load(s) 
}
props.each {
    context.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue(it.key, it.value)
}
```

The above script load test suite level for the current suite where the groovy script is present.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. im getting the following error [org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script4.groovy: 3: unexpected char: '\' @ line 3] i think it may have to do with the file path. any ideas?

Comment: Put your absolute properties file path, but use `/` instead of '\' as path separator. File extension is not really matter, but as a good practice, name  it as `.properties`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in my case I want to have the properties in the same order as the input file, ie. sorted, and this methode does not work. 
I wanted to load a 'Project properties' file containing sorted properties and each time I used this method it stored them unsorted.
I had to use a more straightforward method (see below). If anyone knows about a more elegant/practical way to do it, I'm interested

```
def filename = context.expand( '${#TestCase#filename}' )

def propertiesFile = new File(filename)
assert propertiesFile.exists(), "$filename does not exist"

project = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project

//Remove properties
project.propertyNames.collect{project.removeProperty(it)}

//load the properties of external file
propertiesFile.eachLine {
    line->
    firstIndexOf = line.indexOf('=') // properties as set as key=value in the file
    key = line.substring(0, firstIndexOf)
    value = line.substring(firstIndexOf+1)
    project.setPropertyValue(key, value)
}
```