# SoapUI java API, the TestCase.setPropertyValue operation with a long value blocks the java program

Tags: java, soapui

I'm using SoapUI API version 5.5.0 to execute SoapUI tests from a java test program. I want to pass the service endpoint to test and the input parameters changing the properties of the SoapUI testcase. 
This is the dependence on my pom.xml:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
        <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The program is blocked at execution time when I use a long value for one parameter.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI;
import com.eviware.soapui.StandaloneSoapUICore;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.support.PropertiesMap;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.*;

private static void PutTestCaseProperties(TestCase testCase){

   // Get keys of all properties of this TC     
   Map <String, TestProperty> propertiesTC = testCase.getProperties();
   List<String> lKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
   for(Map.Entry<String, TestProperty> entry : propertiesTC.entrySet()) {
      lKeys.add(entry.getKey());
   }      

   for(String keyTC : lKeys) {
      String keyValue = "pppppp ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp ppppppppppppppppp ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp pppp pppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp pppppppppppppppppppppppppppp pppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp ppppppppppppppppppppppp ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp pppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp pppppppppppppppppppppppppp ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp";

      //String keyValue = "short";

      testCase.setPropertyValue(keyTC, keyValue);
  }
```

}

If I use the "short" value for the keys, the SoapUI test is completely executed, 
but if I use the long value the program is blocked after that.

Is there any length limit in the custom properties of a soapUI test case? I would like to use the parameters to write whole XML files (all built in a text line).
The soapUI program allows to load the custom properties of a test case from a external file. Is it also possible to do it from the soapUI java API?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following solution:

Based on [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723177/soapui-load-custom-properties-from-file-using-groovy) I can load long parameters without errors. Only with the following variation in my groovy to use a properties file which path I configure with a parameter of the Test Case (and I configure this parameter from my Java code using the SoapUI API):

```
def props = new Properties()
//replace the path with your file name below. use / instead of \ as path separator even on windows platform.
new File(context.expand('${#TestCase#propertiesFile}')).withInputStream { s ->
  props.load(s) 
}
props.each {
    context.testCase.setPropertyValue(it.key, it.value)
}
```